# How is the program printing all alphabets even after giving the if condition to find "consonants"

Tags: java, recursion, conditional-operator

I am new to Recursions. I am not able to solve the below problem.

**Problem:** Print the consonants in the string using Recursion. I don't know how the program is printing all alphabets even after giving `if` condition.

```
public static void countCons(String str, int index) {
    if (index >= str.length()) {
        return;
    }
    char x = str.charAt(index);
    if (x != 'a' || x != 'e' || x != 'i' || x != 'o' || x != 'u') {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    index = index + 1;
    countCons(str, index);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion to make `if` statement readable: `if( Arrays.binarySearch("aeiou".toCharArray(), x) < 0 ) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(x!='a'||x!='e'||x!='i'||x!='o'||x!='u')
```

with

```
if (!(x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u'))
```

or with

```
if (x != 'a' && x != 'e' && x != 'i' && x != 'o' && x != 'u')
```

**Let's find the problem with your approach:**

Let's assume `str` is `"aka"`.

When `index` is `0`, x = `'a'`, and therefore `x!='a'||x!='e'||x!='i'||x!='o'||x!='u'` is being evaluated as

```
'a'!='a'||'a'!='e'||'a'!='i'||'a'!='o'||'a'!='u' => false || true || 'a'!='i'||'a'!='o'||'a'!='u' => true
```

When `index` becomes `1`, x = `'k'`, and therefore `x!='a'||x!='e'||x!='i'||x!='o'||x!='u'` is being evaluated as

```
'k'!='a'||'k'!='e'||'k'!='i'||'k'!='o'||'k'!='u' => true || 'k'!='e'||'k'!='i'||'k'!='o'||'k'!='u' => true
```

Note that as soon as multiple conditions are connected with `||`, the evaluation stops as soon as the first `true` condition is found, and the result is concluded as `true`. The result is concluded as `false` only when none of the conditions evaluates to `true`.

On the other hand, when multiple conditions are connected with `&&`, the evaluation stops as soon as the first `false` condition is found, and the result is concluded as `false`. The result is concluded as `true` only when all the conditions evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have use && operator instead of || operator